# python3.8 venv does not work on windows while python3.5 does

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-venv

I have python3.5 and python3.8 on windows and both of them work fine with `virtualenv`.

Recently, I would like to try the standard built-in `venv` instead of `virtualenv` but failed.

When `python3.5 -m venv .env35` it works fine but `python3.8 -m venv .env38` return `Error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`.

Tried about git-bash and powershell, with winty and without winty.

Comment: Have you tried deleting python3.5? It could be a duplicate file that the installer doesn't like or maybe just put it on a seprate drive so that the two can't interact, and what version of windows?

Comment: @discharge nope, and I should not delete python3.5 since I need both... Win10. For now I just use virtualenv insteand of venv....